# spring-data-rest: how to intercept to return api/application specific error messages for 4xx, 5xx?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

spring-data: how to intercept to return api/application specific error messages for 4xx, 5xx?

Spring-data-rest:
Without using a spring controller, I don't find a way to intercept the sql errors/exceptions and return more meaningful messages to the API callers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exception handlers, for example:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionsHandler { 

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> conflict(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new errorMsg(e.getRootCause().getMessage()), CONFLICT);
    }

    ...

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 4)        
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleNotFoundException(NotFoundException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new errorMsg(e.getMessage()), NOT_FOUND);
    }

    ...

    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new errorMsg(e.getMessage()), INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Useful resources:
[Spring Boot - Error Handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling)
[Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#errors-and-rest)
[Error Handling for REST with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)